# JOIN on references

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Why doesn't SQL contain a keyword for specifying a join on columns in one table that references columns in another table?

Like `NATURAL` in a join specifies that it's on columns with the same name.

I often find myself doing something like `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b ON a.b_id=b.id;` where the `b_id` column in `a` is defined to reference the `id` column in `b`. That seems like an awful lot of typing for something quite natural?

Would such a feature be particularly hard to implement or undesirable for some reason that I haven't thought of?

I mostly know SQL from postgresql, so if most other RDBMS'es has such a feature, the questions is just why postgresql doesn't have it.

Comment: Some SQL clients can auto-complete the JOIN condition based on foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

In fact, SQL does.  It is the `USING` clause:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     using (id);
```

As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) explains:

> The USING clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of
>   the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name
>   for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the
>   shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an
>   equality comparison for each one. For example, joining T1 and T2 with
>   USING (a, b) produces the join condition ON T1.a = T2.a AND T1.b =
>   T2.b.

It does still require that the names be the same in the two tables.  But, because the names are explicitly specified in the join condition, this is a safe alternative to `natural join` (which I consider to be a bug waiting to happen).

Comment: But I was specifically asking for something that works when then names are not the same.

Comment: @Henrik . . . That would be the `ON` clause.